# Wiring 3 switches with only 1 hot wire and 6 common wires in single circuit

Tags: wiring

There are 3 neutral (common) wires marked 1, 2 and 3 which are all the old cloth wrapped wires, and a white wire. All neural wires 1, 3x wire 3 and white wire from the light switch and white wire from the timer switch are connected. A dimmer switch for indoor light and a timer switch for outdoor light are connected in series, the dimmer switch to the hot wire 4, and the another black wire from the dimmer switch goes to the timer switch. The white wire from the timer switch is connected to all the neutral wires (total 5 wires), and the blue wire of the timer switch is connected to the wire 1 which is also neutral. There is a neutral wire marked 2 that is not connected. Currently the dimmer switch controls the timer switch. Where do I have to connect the wire 2 in order to make the serial connection[image] of timer and dimmer switch into a parallel connection?

Comment: Can you post photos of what's going on here?  Also, how do you want the timer and dimmer to interact with each other?

Comment: What do you mean by common wires?  Do you mean neutral?  If so you should say neutral.  The word "common" is used for something else that you haven't run into yet (but you soon may).

Comment: Also it seems most of those "common" wires are not white. Code requires neutral be white (North America) or blue (rest of world). What makes you think they are neutral?  "Mere lack of hotness" could be something else.